# In react, in element event listener how to get latest state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

following is my code

```
  var C = () => {
    var [s, setS] = useState(0)
    var dRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>()
    useMount(() => {
      setShortcut("ArrowDown", () => {
        setS(s+1)
      })
    })
    return <div id={"d"} ref={dRef}>{s}</div>
  }
  testReact(<C/>)
  simulateKey("ArrowDown")
  simulateKey("ArrowDown")

export var useMount = (fn: EffectCallback) => {
  useEffect(fn, [] /*2nd arg set fixed make make callback only run when mount*/)
}

export var simulateKey = (key: string) => {
  simulateElementKey(document, key)
}

export var simulateElementKey = (e: HTMLElement | Document, key: string) => {
  if (e instanceof HTMLElement) {
    e.focus();
  }

  // Simulate the keydown event.
  let code = `Key${key.toUpperCase()}`
  e.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key, bubbles: true}));

  // Simulate the keyup event.
  e.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {key, bubbles: true}));
}
```

in code `setS(s+1)`, s always 0, how to get latest state "s" value, I know has setState(prev => {...}), is there getState() to get latest state value

Answer (score 1):

your code is good you need to add a `return` keyword before your `setS(s+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution, use ref sync state value, like following sRef

```
 var C = () => {
    var [s, setS] = useState(0)
    var sRef = useRef<number>()
    sRef.current = s
    var dRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>()
    const getS = useCallback(() => s, [s]);
    useMount(() => {
      setShortcut("ArrowDown", () => {
        setS(sRef.current + 1);
      })
    })
    return <div id={"d"} ref={dRef}>{s}</div>
  }
  testReact(<C/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

when setting state is based on previous state you should use :

```
setS(prevS => prevS+1);
```